# Tensorflow timeline shows the gradients average is the performance bottleneck when using multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use multiple (actually 2) GPUs to train a network. The network works well but I found the training speed fluctuates.

This is the snipet I used for profiling:

```
for i in range(resume_epoch, c.num_epochs):
    print("Epoch %d" % i)
    sess.run(train_itr.initializer)
    num_batches = num_egs // c.batch_size
    for batch in range(num_batches):
        start_time = time.time()
        _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        examples_per_sec = c.batch_size / float(duration)
        print('step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
              'sec/batch)' % (step, loss_value, examples_per_sec, duration))
```

This is the output:

```
...
step 5100, loss = 4.71 (556.3 examples/sec; 0.230 sec/batch)
step 5200, loss = 4.14 (341.9 examples/sec; 0.374 sec/batch)
step 5300, loss = 4.63 (363.4 examples/sec; 0.352 sec/batch)
step 5400, loss = 4.82 (176.0 examples/sec; 0.727 sec/batch)
```

The fastest step can process almost 600 examples/sec, while as shown above, it can also be as slow as ~200 examples/sec.

At the very beginning, I suspected the input pipeline may be the bottleneck. I use the tf.data to process the input features, split and feed them to the different GPU towers. Here is the code:

```
def create_variable_train_dataset(filenames, batch_size, feat_dim, shuffle_size=-1):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames).shuffle(50)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda filename:
                                 tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(
                                 _parse_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=8).shuffle(shuffle_size).apply(                                   
                            tf.contrib.data.padded_batch_and_drop_remainder(
                                   batch_size,
                                   padded_shapes=({'input': [None, feat_dim], 'input_shape': [2], 'output': []}))),
                            cycle_length=len(filenames), block_length=1
                           )

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(5)
    itr = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    element = itr.get_next()
    return itr, element['input'], element['output']
```

In the main function:

```
train_itr, train_feature, train_label = create_variable_train_dataset(train_filenames,
                                                                          batch_size=c.batch_size,
                                                                          feat_dim=feat_dim,
                                                                          shuffle_size=400000//len(train_filenames))
features_splits = tf.split(train_feature, num_or_size_splits=c.num_gpus, axis=0)

tower_grads = []
reuse_variables = None
for i in range(c.num_gpus):
    with tf.device(assign_to_device('/gpu:{}'.format(i), ps_device=c.local_ps_device)):
        with tf.name_scope('tower_%d' % i) as scope:
            loss = _tower_loss(features_splits[i], labels_splits[i], num_classes, scope, reuse_variables)
            reuse_variables = True
            grad = ...some_function_to_compute_grad
            tower_grads.append(grads)
grads = _average_gradients(tower_grads)
```

_tower_loss is a function to make tower loss in different GPUs, while the parameters are kept in CPU.

```
def _tower_loss(features, labels, num_classes, scope, reuse_variables=None):
    # Build inference Graph.
    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=reuse_variables):
        logits = inference(features, num_classes, is_training=True, scope=scope)

    tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits, scope="loss")

    losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES, scope)
    regularization_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
    total_loss = tf.add_n(losses + regularization_losses, name='total_loss')

    # Compute the moving average of all individual losses and the total loss.
    loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
    loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(losses + [total_loss])

    with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
        total_loss = tf.identity(total_loss)

    return total_loss
```

Next, I used the Timeline tool to inspect the time elapse during training. To my surprise, the CPU takes really long time. Here is what I have done.

```
start_time = time.time()
if step % 100 == 0:
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)
 else:
    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
    duration = time.time() - start_time
```

Here is the result of the last step above (step 5400, loss = 4.82 (176.0 examples/sec; 0.727 sec/batch)):
[timeline result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fipP.png)

As you see, CPU:0 takes really long time. 
[Expand the cpu operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWgNK.png)

The Concat, Mean and ApplyAdam() take the most time. They come from the _average_gradients function:

```
def _average_gradients(tower_grads):
    average_grads = []
    for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
        # Note that each grad_and_vars looks like the following:
        #   ((grad0_gpu0, var0_gpu0), ... , (grad0_gpuN, var0_gpuN))
        grads = []
        for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
            # Add 0 dimension to the gradients to represent the tower.
            expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)

            # Append on a 'tower' dimension which we will average over below.
            grads.append(expanded_g)

        # Average over the 'tower' dimension.
        grad = tf.concat(axis=0, values=grads)
        grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)

        # Keep in mind that the Variables are redundant because they are shared
        # across towers. So .. we will just return the first tower's pointer to
        # the Variable.
        v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
        grad_and_var = (grad, v)
        average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
    return average_grads
...
grads = _average_gradients(tower_grads)
apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
```

This is reasonable because the gradients should be averaged after GPU computation. But how can I improve the performance? I implement my model by refering to [the inception example in tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py). I use tensorflow 1.4.0.

Any advice to improve the training speed?

If any other codes, files or information is helpful to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Yi Bill - Your chance of getting a good response will be much higher if you ask only one question.  Looking at your code, the opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step) implies that the gradients are sent from all the GPUs to 1 GPU (or CPU) and processed in that one place.  The gradient matrix is *as large as your whole network* and sending it from GPU to GPU is a non-trivial amount of network load.  Most likely it is sent to GPU 0 and processed there.  Try another experiment where you only compute the gradient on 1 variable (like the bottleneck).

Comment: @Panchishin I edited the question to focus on the main problem :-) At the beginning of the code, I use with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0') to clarify the gradient descent is done at cpu:0. I know the transfer of data from the host and device would be a huge overhead, but tensorflow tutorial suggest this framework when using multiple gpus. Now I change the parameter server from the cpu to gpu:0 since my device supprot p2p transfer. I will check the performance and try your suggestion later.

Answer (score 0):

I try to move the gradient average and gradient descend to GPU:0. Because my GPUs have peer2peer connections, the data move is fast and the computation in GPU is also fast. Place all these ops in the first GPU nearly solve my problem. It is welcomed if anyone has other comments :D