# No Multi-GPU speed up for GAN

Tags: tensorflow

I've got a [codebase](https://github.com/LucasSloan/GAN) where I try to replicate GAN papers.  I recently bought a second gpu, and I'm trying to update my code to take advantage of the additional hardware.  I tried the approach outlined in the Tensorflow [cifar10 multi-gpu example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py).  However, when I run the my code with 2 gpus, it doesn't run any faster, in fact, it runs about 10% slower than if I run with a single gpu.  Looking at resource manager, it says that both of my gpus are running at about 50% capacity.

I'm running on Windows 10, with python 3.7, TF 1.13.  I'm using 2 2080ti's with a 2950 cpu.

My first thought was that there was trouble with my input pipeline, so I tried a number of variations, such as using multiple data iterators, using tf.data.experimental.prefetch_to_device(), not feeding in my latent vector, etc.  None had any affect, and since my CPU utilization was about 5% with each, I'm pretty sure I'm not bottle necked there.

I've also tried some variations in how I set up the variable scopes for the towers, but that didn't help.

I also tried doubling the batch size in case I was just not putting enough data through the gpus, but that resulted in taking 2x as long to compute each batch, with the same 50% gpu utilization.

My code is [here](https://github.com/LucasSloan/GAN/blob/master/gan.py), and the relevant portion is:

```py
        d_grads = []
        g_grads = []
        for i in range(FLAGS.num_gpus):
            with tf.device('/gpu:{:d}'.format(i)):
                with tf.variable_scope('D', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                    Dx, Dx_logits = self.discriminator(xs[i], yxs[i])
                with tf.variable_scope('G', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                    G = self.generator(z[i], labels[i])
                with tf.variable_scope('D', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                    Dg, Dg_logits = self.discriminator(G, labels[i])

                loss_d, loss_g = self.losses(Dx_logits, Dg_logits, Dx, Dg)

                vars = tf.trainable_variables()
                for v in vars:
                    print(v.name)
                d_params = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith('D/')]
                g_params = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith('G/')]

                d_grads.append(d_adam.compute_gradients(loss_d, var_list=d_params))
                g_grads.append(g_adam.compute_gradients(loss_g, var_list=g_params))

        d_opt = d_adam.apply_gradients(average_gradients(d_grads))
        g_opt = g_adam.apply_gradients(average_gradients(g_grads))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `gan.py` file see line 17 [num_gpus](https://github.com/LucasSloan/GAN/blob/master/gan.py#L17) has been set as 1. Secondly, check this link for [Allowing GPU memory growth](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth). By default, TensorFlow maps nearly all of the GPU memory of all GPUs (subject to CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES) visible to the process. In some cases it is desirable for the process to only allocate a subset of the available memory, or to only grow the memory usage as is needed by the process. TensorFlow provides two Config options on the Session to control this.

The first is the `allow_growth` option, which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory based on runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as `Sessions` get run and more GPU memory is needed.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

The second method is the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` option, which determines the fraction of the overall amount of memory that each visible GPU should be allocated. For example, you can tell TensorFlow to only allocate 40% of the total memory of each GPU by:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

This is useful if you want to truly bound the amount of GPU memory available to the TensorFlow process.

**Using a single GPU on a multi-GPU system**

If you have more than one GPU in your system, the GPU with the lowest ID will be selected by default. If you would like to run on a different GPU, you will need to specify the preference explicitly:

***# Creates a graph.***

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

If the device you have specified does not exist, you will get `InvalidArgumentError`:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device to node 'b':
Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:2'
   [[{ {node b}} = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [3,2]
   values: 1 2 3...>, _device="/device:GPU:2"]()]]
```

If you would like TensorFlow to automatically choose an existing and supported device to run the operations in case the specified one doesn't exist, you can set `allow_soft_placement` to True in the configuration option when creating the session.

***# Creates a graph.***

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with allow_soft_placement and log_device_placement set
# to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

**Using multiple GPUs**

If you would like to run TensorFlow on multiple GPUs, you can construct your model in a multi-tower fashion where each tower is assigned to a different GPU. For example:

***# Creates a graph.***

```
c = []
for d in ['/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
    c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  sum = tf.add_n(c)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(sum))
```

Comment: Good point about the flag, when I want to run with 2 gpus, I pass in --num_gpus=2.

I'm not sure what your emphasis on memory is for?  I can see in the performance monitor that ~all the memory on both my gpus is being taken up.  I can see that both of them are computing, but each at only half capacit.

Comment: I think your multi-gpu hardware configuration on your system is not setup right. Could you run the following command to share your GPUs layout: `nvidia-smi topo -m` and paste the output. For details check Multiple GPUs slower than single GPU (https://github.com/avolkov1/keras_experiments/issues/13)

Comment: When I try to run that command, I get `Invalid combination of input arguments. Please run 'nvidia-smi -h' for help.`.  According to [this pdf](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf), the topo command is linux only, and I'm running on windows.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I ran the bandwidthTest suggested at your link.  It said that CPU - GPU bandwidth was 12699.6 MB/s and that GPU - GPU bandwidth was 517367.7 MB/s.

Comment: I also tried the suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843171/tensorflow-timeline-shows-the-gradients-average-is-the-performance-bottleneck-wh) to locate the gradient averaging explicitly on gpu:0, but that didn't help.